# How to print a huge number of images in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, printing

I have `PrintTest.aspx` page load images paths from database and render it in div to print **these images maybe up to 20000 image**  .

```
       for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count; i++)
    {
    HtmlImage image=new HtmlImage();
        image.ID="ImageAN"+i.ToString();
        image.Src=Files[i].ToString();
        image.Alt="PrintImage";
        image.Attributes.Add("class","PrintImage");

    div_Print.Controls.Add(image);
    }
```

Then call JavaScript function to print the content of div_Print

```
 this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ClientScript", " PrintContent('div_Print')", true);
```

java-script function  >

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function PrintContent(divName) {
    var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById(divName);
    var WindowObject = window.open();
    WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
}
</script>
```

But this scenario causes my browser keep crashing and closed.

I want any scenario to avoid this or print images without render it inside HTML

Comment: That's too much for a web browser, you'll have to split it into separate chunks, and print fewer images at a time.

Comment: @bfavaretto, that doesn't make sense. The data would be spooled to the printer over *n* amount of time yes? Who cares how big the page is, it will just take a long time to print.

Comment: @neoistheone I believe the browser is crashing even before sending anything to the printer... If e.g. each image is 50KB, the whole page is 1GB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't . This is why people invented pagination and search.

And there are several reasons why:

- Memory is a limited resource, especially on mobile devices (if you support them)
- TMI, people cannot visually understand 20k images put on a single page, without spending hours staring at it

Something like this

```
public ControlsTypeHere PrintImages(int take, int skip)
{
    int filesPrinted;

    for (int i = skip; i < Files.Count; i++)
    {
        if(filesPrinted >= take)
            break;

        HtmlImage image=new HtmlImage();
        image.ID="ImageAN"+i.ToString();
        image.Src=Files[i].ToString();
        image.Alt="PrintImage";
        image.Attributes.Add("class","PrintImage");

        div_Print.Controls.Add(image);

        filesPrinted++;
    }

    return div_Print.Controls;
}
```

Comment: ok there is any way to print by divide these images to stages every stage contains 100 image or something like this

Comment: Yes there is, but it depends on your technology. The idea is you have an image source (database, file system) and you enumerate the images from the source. Once you read a chunk, you process it (print, show to user). If a user/process requests more, you read the next chunk. So your reading function will need to accept two parameters: skip and take. Skip tells the function how many images you have already processed, and take tells it how many new images to return.